# Syntax highlighting for comments in Magit commit buffers with custom core.commentChar

Tags: magit, git, markdown-mode

I frequently source the body of my GitHub PRs from my commits, and thus is makes sense to consider my commits to be made in Markdown (it is nice to have a markup language for commits anyway). Thus I customized Magit's `git-commit-major-mode` to be `markdown-mode`, but then all the `#` comment lines that Git inserts get formatted like markdown headers---highly undesirable! So I switched away from `#` as Git's comment delimiter. Somewhat randomly, I picked `!`, and added to my `.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    commentChar = !
```

This keeps them from being formatted like headers, but I previously enjoyed the way that Magit had some understanding of these lines and would syntax-highlight them. I was hoping that there was some intelligence in the Git commit mode that would be able to mesh markdown mode with the original abilities of Magit, so that *above* the comment lines would be highlighted with Markdown, and the comment lines themselves would be highlighted by Magit (which is already aware of `core.commentChar`, because when I set commit buffers to have no major mode, it properly highlights the comments that use `!`).

My current configuration is usable, but with Emacs (and Magit especially) I always shoot for the stars. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Try setting the comment-start variable using git-commit-setup-hook.

Comment: @tarsius Thanks for the hint. I tried it haven't gotten the setting of `comment-start` to take. I added `(defun kazark/!-as-comment-char () (setq-local comment-start "!"))` to my `.spacemacs` and then used `customize` to add that to `git-commit-setup-hook`. However, it makes no difference, and when I check the value of `comment-start` in that buffer, it is still `<!--`.

Comment: @tarsius even if I just eval `(setq-local comment-start "!")` in that buffer, which does set `comment-start`, nothing changes.

Comment: Actually this is supposed to work without you doing anything except setting the git variable `core.commentChar`. That's implemented in `git-commit-setup-font-lock`. I just tested it and it works for me. I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Maybe you are using a very old version of the `git-commit` package.

Comment: @tarsius yeah, that makes sense; that is what I would expect. My `git-commit` version is `20200828.1753` though: very new.

Comment: Try to reproduce with `emacs -Q`, see https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Debugging-Tools.html.

Comment: @tarsius thanks, I'll give that a shot if I can. I don't really know how to use Emacs from scratch; to date I have been Spacemacs-only so I get a little lost in bare Emacs mode. If you don't hear back from me, I'm probably lost in that. :)

Comment: I don't know enough about Spacemacs to help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supposed to already work. Figuring out why it doesn't work for you will require a debugging effort on your part and I am afraid I won't be able to help you any more with that because I do not know enough about Spacemacs to do so. I suggest you ask for help from some other Spacemacs users.

Comment: A coworker who has his own Emacs configuration confirmed your results, and I submitted a [Spacemacs issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/14195). Because this appears to be a Spacemacs bug, I think it is reasonable to consider this the accepted answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have a [fix](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/14197) for Spacemacs. Turns out `mmm-mode` was clobbering the correct behavior.